# show data when user click on button in side-nave - html

Tags: javascript, html, css, django-templates

how to show data when user click on button in side-nave , i have side-nave in my html and i want when user click on `about` for example  it show about data

my code :

```
<!-- The sidebar -->
<div class="sidenav">
  <br><br><br>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="#about">
    <p> hello {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}  </p>
    <hr>
    <p>
  <button style="background-color:#7952b3" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    show data
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <p>Your name is - {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</p>
    <p>Your email is - {{user.email}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

i tried this but when i click on about in nave-side it don't show my data why ?

when user click on about button for example it should show about how to do this

Comment: please share the code you have tried

Comment: okay i will edit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The sidebar -->
<div class="sidenav">
  <br><br><br>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="about" style='display:none;'>
    <p> hello {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}  </p>
    <hr>
    <p>
  <button style="background-color:#7952b3" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    show data
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <p>Your name is - {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</p>
    <p>Your email is - {{user.email}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidenav a').on('click', function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("href");
    $(x).toggle();
  })

});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it work perfect ! , and when user click again on about how to hide data

Comment: Change the hide() to toggle(). That should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
         #myDIV {
         width: 100%;
         padding: 50px 0;
         text-align: center;
         background-color: lightblue;
         margin-top: 20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <div id="myDIV">
         This is my DIV element.
      </div>
      <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
           var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
           if (x.style.display === "none") {
             x.style.display = "block";
           } else {
             x.style.display = "none";
           }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick event with a possiblity to hide another field with css with {display:none;} until is active? Check this link and tell me if it solves your problem. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp